# Unable to install tor, access to directories denied

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

How to proceed? I'm trying to install tor and I'm not able to run the command

```
apt-get update
```

I'm getting the above errors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run this command as the root user, or at least use `sudo` to grant you super user permissions.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It worked. At least the process is now going on. It was such an easy thing. Thanks a ton. Will try learning more.